# Visual Studio for Mac - Build very slow, stuck

Tags: xamarin

I have ported a Xamarin Studio app that use Xamarin Forms, iOS/Android to Visual Studio for Mac. All my other apps build fine but for some reason this specific app doesn't want to build at all, it is stuck half way in the build process.

I deleted the bin and obj folders.
I have done a Clean, even the clean takes long.
The packages folder is up to date etc.
I do have the latest update from the Stable branch.

Not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: Same issue - managed to get my project to build after leaving my mac for literally over an hour

Answer (score 1):

I had this too. I opened XCode on the mac and there was an prompt for installing additional components waiting for me. I answered yes and then restarted VS.net when it completed and now it builds fine.​

Answer (score 0):

I can second this; there is no visual indication that anything is wrong with the build it just churns away. Opening XCode and clicking yes to the dialog that additional components still needed to be installed worked for me as well.